# Mysql: How to lock a whole table during transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I have a transaction like this (innoDB):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE id > 5; // Let's assume this returns 0 rows

// Some very long operation here

//If the previous SELECT contained 0 results, this Insert will be executed
INSERT INTO test VALUES...;
COMMIT;
```

Now the problem is that if more sessions execute at the same time, then they will all end up executing the INSERT, because by the time the *long task* in those sessions has finished, all of the sessions had plenty of time to do the SELECT, and it will return 0 row result for all of them, since the INSERT haven't been executed quite yet due to the long task running.

So basically, I need to somehow lock the whole table `test` (so it can't be read by other sessions and they will be forced to wait)  after I execute START TRANSACTION, but I am not sure how, because I can't use the  `LOCK TABLES test` query, because that COMMITs the transaction I have started.
I also cannot use SELECT .. FOR UPDATE, because that only prevents existing rows from being modified, but it won't prevent new rows from being inserted.

Comment: Why you are not using MyISAM for this table.

Comment: @SINGH what does that have to do with anything? how would that help anyway? MyISAM doesn't support transactions at all.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html `SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;`

Comment: @ADyson thanks. But he want to lock the reading of that table also.

Comment: @SINGH only because he's thinking about the problem in the wrong way - see my answer. No need to read the table at all, it's the wrong solution to the problem. And anyway switching to MyISAM will not solve the problem because we have to assume transactional integrity of the inserts is still required, since a transaction is being used (otherwise, it something fails, it's hard to resume the job halfway through). If that wasn't an issue, then the question would be unnecessary - the answer would simply be to remove the transaction,and I'm pretty sure the OP would have tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got some long-running task which only needs to be run once, set a flag in a separate table to say that the task has started, and check *that* instead of the number of rows written to the target table, so that another instance of the service does not kick off the job twice.

This also has the advantage that you're not relying on the specifics of the task in order to know the status of it (and therefore if the nature of the task changes, the integrity of your other code doesn't collapse), and you're not trying to work round the transaction by doing something horrible like locking an entire table. One of the points of using transactions is that it's not necessary to lock everything (although of course different isolation levels can be used, but that's not the subject of this discussion).

Then set the flag back to false when the last bit of the task has finished.

Comment: its good but it will increase two queries like first to update or insert a flag in another table then again reset query for that flag after commit the transaction. What do you think?

Comment: @SINGH a couple of queries to set a boolean flag true or false will be so trivial in terms of performance impact that it's barely worth mentioning.